# angular 2 Display table row data in bootstrap popup

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, popup

I have a html table which created using a ng-For in my angular 2 application.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Doctor </th>
                    <th>Patient Name</th>
                    <th>Age </th>
                    <th>Other Info</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let meeting of historyItems">
                    <td>{{meeting.doctorName}}</td>
                    <td>{{meeting.patientName}}</td>
                    <td>{{meeting.patientAge}}</td>
      <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="onDisplayInfo(meeting)"  >Info</button>
                </td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

On click of the button in the row I need to display all the information in the row in a bootstrap popup. 
But I searched a lot and unable to find a way to display each row data in the popup.

how ever I can display a popup with static content but i need to display a dynamic popup with clicked row info.

is any way to do it easily

Comment: can you show the code of this `onDisplayInfo` method?

Comment: what kind of dynamic popup you wanna display? do you mean dynamic component?

Comment: @omeralper I need to display row  information in bootstrap modal popup.
The thing is I know how to display a modal popup programatically with static template. But how can I display each row info on a dynamic template

Comment: @Aravind .. currently I haven't implemented that